# convert JSON object to collections which implements IEnumerable

Tags: c#, json, ienumerable

how can I convert JSON object to Collections that implement IEnumerable so that I can use in **foreach**

ERROR: **"foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'Attributes' because 'Attributes' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'  "**
the .net code to traverse Attributes:

```
var jsonData  = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(json); 
//RootObject  is the class generated from Json using Paste JSON as Classes    
var att = jsonData.AnswerTA.Attributes;
            foreach (var item in att)<-- This is giving error
            {}
```

Part of JSON file:

```
  {  "FormTitle": "This is Form Title from JSON",  
"TitleQuestion1": "This s the Title of Question 1",  
"TextQuestion1": "1-    This is the text of Quextion umber 1",            "AnswerRadioButton": {    "visibleRB": "true",    "titleRB": "Radio Button Title",
"FieldsetRB": "yes",
"optionRB": [
  {
    "text": "text1",
    "value": "v1",
    "checked": "false"
  },
  {
    "text": "text2",
    "value": "v2",
    "checked": "false"
  },
  {
    "text": "text3",
    "value": "v3",
    "checked": "false"
  },
  {
    "text": "text4",
    "value": "v4",
    "checked": "true"
  },
  {
    "text": "text5",
    "value": "v4",
    "checked": "false"
  }
  ]
 },      "AnswerCheckBox": {     "visibleCB": "true",    "titleCB": "Check box Answer Title",    "FieldsetCB": "yes",    "optionCB": [
  {        "text": "ch text1",        "value": "v1",        "checked": "false"      },      {        "text": "tzxcsdcext2",        "value": "v2",
    "checked": "false"
  },
  {        "text": "text3",        "value": "v3",        "checked": "false"
  },
  {        "text": "text4",        "value": "v4",        "checked": "true"
  }
]},  "AnswerDropDownList": {    "visibleDDl": "true",    "required": "no",    "titleDDL": "Title of Drop Down List ",    "FieldsetDDL": "yes",    "optionDDL": [      {        "text": "Select",        "value": ""      },
  {        "text": "IE",        "value": "IE"      },      {
    "text": "Safari",        "value": "Safari"      },
  {        "text": "Chrome",        "value": "Chrome"
  }    ]  },  "AnswerTB": {    "visibleTB": "true",    "required": "no",
"titleTB": "Title of TB ",    "FieldsetTB": "yes"  },  
"AnswerTA": {
"visibleTA": "true",
"required": "no",
"titleTA": "Title of TA ",
"FieldsetTA": "yes",
"Attributes": {
  "placeholder": "this is the watermark",
  "title": "this is tooltip",
  "maxlength": "10",
  "minlength": "5",
  "required": "yes"
},
"Style": {
  "height": "50px",
  "width" :  "5px"
}
```

}
}

Classes generated

```
public class Rootobject{
public string FormTitle { get; set; }
public string TitleQuestion1 { get; set; }
public string TextQuestion1 { get; set; }
public Answerradiobutton AnswerRadioButton { get; set; }
public Answercheckbox AnswerCheckBox { get; set; }
public Answerdropdownlist AnswerDropDownList { get; set; }
public Answertb AnswerTB { get; set; }
public Answerta AnswerTA { get; set; }
}

public class Answerta{
public string visibleTA { get; set; }
public string required { get; set; }
public string titleTA { get; set; }
public string FieldsetTA { get; set; }
public Attributes Attributes { get; set; }
public Style Style { get; set; }
}
public class Attributes{
public string placeholder { get; set; }
public string title { get; set; }
public string maxlength { get; set; }
public string minlength { get; set; }
public string required { get; set; }}
```

Comment: Post your classes and full json.

Comment: The `Attributes` text in your Json string is a *single* object, not an array. Arrays are enclosed in square brackets  `[]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your json sample "Attributes" is not an array. 
If you want to enumerate Attributes it needs to be defined as an array:

```
 "Attributes":[ {
   "placeholder": "this is the watermark",
   "title": "this is tooltip",
   "maxlength": "10",
   "minlength": "5",
   "required": "yes"
 },
 { 
   "placeholder": "this is the watermark",
   "title": "this is tooltip",
   "maxlength": "10",
   "minlength": "5",
   "required": "yes"
 } ],
```

Or, you need to make Attributes class [implement IEnumerable interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11296810/how-do-i-implement-ienumerablet).

[Also, you can enumerate the properties of Attributes by using reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4276566/how-can-you-loop-over-the-properties-of-a-class)

Comment: I dont want to make Attributes an array, However can u show me how can I make Attributes class implement IEnumerable interface.

Comment: @Shomaali Your `Attribute` snippet is a dictionary that's typically deserialized as a single object. If you want the dictionary itself instead of the object, change `Attributes` to a `Dictionary<string,string>`

Comment: I agree with PKanavos, but if you insist on making it IEnumerable the following link will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11296810/how-do-i-implement-ienumerablet

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos I also agree with you. Can u show me how to change Attributes to a Dictionary<string,string>