# How to use for() loop to do the value assignment operation in C#?

Tags: c#

I have a DataModel class in my C# program like below.

```
    public class DataModel
    {
        public string num1 { get; set; }
        public string num2 { get; set; }
        public string num3 { get; set; }
        public string num4 { get; set; }
        public string num5 { get; set; }
    }
```

I need to do value assignment as below. The left side `num1..num5` are `TextBlock`. The right side `data.num1..data.num5` are initialized in another page already and will assign them to TextBlock's Text property.  How to make it by using a for() loop? Thanks!

```
    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Parameter != null && e.Parameter is DataModel)
        {
            var data = e.Parameter as DataModel;
            string str;

            num1TextBlock.Text = data.num1;
            num2TextBlock.Text = data.num2;
            num3TextBlock.Text = data.num3;
            num4TextBlock.Text = data.num4;
            num5TextBlock.Text = data.num5;
```

Sorry for the unclear description. Updated, please check again. Thanks!

**More:**
If the array count is not fixed to 5 (5 is the minimal count), for example, we pull data from our server and after that we know how much data we need to do the assignment(initializing). How to do it?

Comment: your question is not clear at all.

Comment: You cannot in a nice way. Instead you could consider using an array instead of `num1`, `num2`, `num3`...

Comment: Possibly a duplicate with [how can you loop over the properties of a class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4276566/how-can-you-loop-over-the-properties-of-a-class)

Comment: If you put your TextBlocks into a Panel you will be able to use Panel.Children property to get them and make array based on element names. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.panel.children#Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_Panel_Children But better use MVVM pattern

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place your TextBlocks into an array.

```
var nums = new TextBlock[] {num1, num2, num3, num4, num5 };
```

Refactor your DataModel to also use an array instead of five fields, like so:

```
public class DataModel
{
   public string[] nums {get; set;} 
}
```

Then you can do:

```
for(int i = 0; i < data.nums.Length; i++)
{
    nums[i].Text = data.nums[i];
}
```

Of course you should check if the number of data fields and the number of TextBlocks match up before running the loop, to avoid any `IndexOutOfRange` exceptions,

Answer (score 0):

Something like below:

```
    TextBlock[] blocks = new[]{num1, num2, num3, num4, num5};
    int[] values = new[]{data.num1, data.num2, data.num3, data.num4, data.num5};
    for (int i = 0; i<5;++i)
       blocks[i].Text = values[i].ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't really loop like that in C#. You can use an array, or even better, use a Dictionary. Dictionaries map really well into javascript objects, this:

```
var dataModel = new Dictionary<string, string>()
{
    { "num1", "string1" },
    { "num2", "string2" },
    { "num3", "string3" },
    { "num4", "string4" },
    { "num5", "string5" },
};
```

would easily map into this:

```
{
    num1: "string1",
    num2: "string2",
    num3: "string3",
    num4: "string4",
    num5: "string5"
}
```

You can, however, use Reflection to get all properties of DataModel, iterate over them and match them by name with properties from another model and copy the values, but I wouldn't recommend it.