# How to process FromQuery parameters in C# / ASP.NET Core in the order they were sent?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a `GET` endpoint which receives a `[FromQuery]` object which contains columns from a grid. The user can sort those columns as they want and I have to respect that order to export them to a `.CSV` file.

How can I find out the order the column names were sent in the `[FromQuery]` parameter? I'm using .NET Core 6 with C#

I tried looping over the parameter names (properties) with a `foreach` as described on this article:

[How can you loop over the properties of a class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4276566/how-can-you-loop-over-the-properties-of-a-class)

but I can only get the parameters in the order they were declared in the parameter class.

I'm expecting to get the real order they were sent in the `FromQuery` string.

Comment: Preserving the order of query parameters with the same name is not a feature (https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/24622), but the order of elements will be preserved if the query parameter is explicit. eg `sort[0]=`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could parse the query string directly within your controller, into a dictionary. Then you know the order they were received because they were added to the dictionary in that order.

In your controller's action method...

```
var qs = Request.QueryString;
var qsd = new Dictionary<string, string>();
string[] qsa = qs.Value.Split(new char[] {'&', '?'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
foreach(var item in qsa)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(item)) continue;
    var keyAndValue = item.Split('=', 2, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    qsd.Add(keyAndValue[0], keyAndValue[1]);
}
```

Comment: Good practical solution, but as a little addendum it would probably be better to use an OrderedDictionary as officially the Dictionary<> is not guaranteed to preserve order.

Comment: Thank you, it worked. I just wanted to clarify that in my case the Request.Querystring part was enough to pass the parameters order to the methods in the back. I understand a Dictionary may be very useful if what you receive are column internal names along with their respective titles, but in my case I only receive their internal names and get their titles in the back methods.

Comment: Now that I uploaded the code to the UAT server (kubernetes in AWS), I find it behaves different. The Request.QueryString is returning a querystring with all the parameters ordered alphabetically, so now I'm not getting the real order of them sent by the front. I've been searching but can't find another way round. Do you have any ideas of why this is happening there but not in my localhost environment?

Comment: @Javier I don't know enough about AWS to answer that. I think you should post a new question showing an example of the querystring you send and show or explain what happens after AWS receives the request. And tag your question with amazon-web-services, and aws-api-gateway.